# how to loop through a array of objects and match to a database and return matching with linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, asp.net-web-api2

I need to pass in ids to a webapi controller and return the result. I am currently passing in the ids as a array of objects. I need to match the ids with a dataset and return the result. I found a couple of posts that I am trying to use.

```
 return db.markets.Where(x => db.markets.Contains(x.x_market_code));
```

this does not work because the it is not a string or list? I have tried to convert the array to a string or list and i have not got anywhere.

here is code

```
 public class marketIds
{
    public int x_market_code { get; set; }
}

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("getAssignedMarkets")]
    public IQueryable GetAssignedMarkets(marketIds[] arry)
    {
      return db.markets.Where(x => arry.Contains(x.x_market_code));
    }
```

I can change how i pass the ids in javascript if need be.

error message
[image]

Comment: What about `.ToList();` at the end of your code??

Comment: nope didnt do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume market code is int so:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("getAssignedMarkets")]
public IQueryable GetAssignedMarkets(int[] arry)
{
  return db.markets.Where(x => arry.Contains(x.x_market_code));
}
```

but you can use string or whatever,
however you can still use your class:

```
 public class marketIds
{
    public int x_market_code { get; set; }
}

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("getAssignedMarkets")]
    public IQueryable GetAssignedMarkets(marketIds[] arry)
    {
      return db.markets.Where(x => arry.where(t=>t.x_market_code == x.x_market_code).Any());
    }
```

based on your error message , maybe this will help you:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("getAssignedMarkets")]
public IQueryable GetAssignedMarkets(int[] arry)
{
  return db.markets.Where(x => arry.Contains(x.x_market_code.Value)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: the watch is "Enumeration yielded no results"

Answer (score 1):

You can convert read all the `market_code`s from the array to a collection of strings and then use `Contains()` method in your LINQ query.

```
var codeList = arry.Select(s => s.x_market_code).ToList();
var result=db.markets.Where(x => codeList.Contains(x.x_market_code));
return result;
```

Assuming you are comparing it against the `market_code` column in your market table and it is of type `Int`.